# How do I get the values of the sRGB gamut and AdobeRGB Rating of my screen on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04, color-management, icc

I have started dabbling into Photo Editing and wanted to know the performance of my screen. I do not know however how to find the **sRGB** and **AdobeRGB** coverage of my laptop's screen. Is there a way to do that on Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

You’d need hardware via a colorimeter or spectrometer, as well as software such as DisplayCal.

With that said, neither Windows nor Linux are fully coloring managed operating systems, and don’t even manage window decorations, UI, nor wallpapers. They are colossal failures that leave the job of colour management up to the applications to choose to manage or not.

Bottom line is that if your display is wide gamut you are in for a garishly over saturated and wonky experience on those two operating systems.